# C# beginner q about dataGrid columns

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

So being new to C# I ran into a problem with formatting a datagrid's columns.
So, I populate my grid like this:

```
SQLiteDataAdapter adapter = new SQLiteDataAdapter("select * from table", myDBCon);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(ds);
myDBCon.Close();
dataGridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

And I want to be able to decide myself what is the order of the displayed columns and what columns not to show.
I tried adding columns manually to the control using it's context menu, but I ended up having a grid with my declared columns, followed by ALL the columns, shown again...
I only want the columns I declared to be shown, not all, and just ONCE, not twice.
I must be missing a simple setting somewhere, otherwise adding columns at design time would be pointless

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you know that you can choose the columns and the order of the columns directly in the sql text? _select col3, col1, col2 from table_

Comment: Yes I know that, thank you :) I am a CSharp beginner, not a programming beginner. But I want to have the functionality of chosing the columns from the grid, since winforms offers this option

Comment: In Delphi, if I don't add columns to a DBGrid, then the grid shows me all columns in the query, and if I declare the columns then it only shows me the declared columns. I find that approach very logical. I just want to have a similar functionality here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried adding columns manually to the control using it's context
>   menu, but I ended up having a grid with my declared columns, followed
>   by ALL the columns, shown again

Set `DataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false`
Then only predefined columns will be used

I am not sure, but afraid this setting cannot be set through designer. Just put it in the constructor of Form after `InitializeComponents()`

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. And no, it cannot be set at designtime in the properties of the datagrid, but it works when I set it in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go through all the hassle of defining the columns in code or designer, you could remove the unwanted columns by simply turning off the visibility. They would still be there but not visible

```
dataGridView4.Columns["some_column_name"].Visible = false;
```

If there are multiple places where you assign a datatable to the grid, you could use the *DataSourceChanged* event:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    dataGridView4.DataSourceChanged += dataGridView4_DataSourceChanged;
}

void dataGridView4_DataSourceChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataGridView datagrid = sender as DataGridView;
    if (datagrid != null)
    {
       datagrid.Columns["some_column_name"].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use LINQ to filter your data (by adding `using System.Linq;` at the top of your code):

```
dataGridView4.DataSource = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                             .Select(row => new 
                                            {
                                                Id = row.Field<int>("Id"),
                                                Column2 = row.Field<string>("Column2"),
                                                Col3 = ... // Put here the columns you want
                                            })
                             .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: I was looking for a `simple` solution to display only the designtime added columns. Fabio understood my question better. Thank you